# cpp file not compiling in clang++ and g++

Tags: c++, c++11, encoding, utf-8, clang

I have been working on C++ for few years now and have compiled stuff several times but the following issue is totally new to me and it just doesn't make sense.

Following are the steps i am following:

- using cygwin setup with g++ version:6.4.0 and clang++ version:4.0.1
- created a new cpp fie using sublime text added simple cout and compiled
  with the command: clang++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 thread1.cpp -o thread, works fine.
- added new contents maybe another cout, this time upon compilation i
  get a ton of errors stating its not utf-8 file.
- saved the file using utf-8 encoding in sublime text and also tried
  with utf-8 BOM encoding, still getting same not utf-8 file error.
- ran the file command in cygwin to check file encoding , file -i
  thread1.cpp, got output as thread1.cpp: text/x-c; charset=utf-8.

Any pointers to what might be going wrong here?

Following is the code which compiles:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include "mutex"
using namespace std;

class threadFunctor{
        public:

};
int main(int argc , char** argv){
   cout << "Hello";
   return 0;
}
```

Following code gives error:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include "mutex"
using namespace std;

class threadFunctor{
        public:
};
int main(int argc , char** argv){
   cout << "Hello World";
   return 0;
}
```

Following is a snippet of the errors generated:

```
./thread:3:29: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
$<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>PE<U+0000><U+0000>d<86><U+0014><U+0000><87><F5><CC>Y<U+0000><U+0014><U+0001><U+0000><A9><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><F0><U+0000>'...
                                                                                                                                                                         ^
./thread:3:30: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
$<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>PE<U+0000><U+0000>d<86><U+0014><U+0000><87><F5><CC>Y<U+0000><U+0014><U+0001><U+0000><A9><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><F0><U+0000>'...
                                                                                                                                                                             ^
./thread:3:31: warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
$<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>PE<U+0000><U+0000>d<86><U+0014><U+0000><87><F5><CC>Y<U+0000><U+0014><U+0001><U+0000><A9><U+0002><U+0000><U+0000><F0><U+0000>'...
                                                                                                                                                                                     ^
./thread:4:3: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
5<U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><E8><B0><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><C4><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><C8><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><CC>...
         ^
./thread:4:4: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
5<U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><E8><B0><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><C4><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><C8><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><CC>...
                 ^
./thread:4:5: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
5<U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><E8><B0><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><C4><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><C8><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000>E1<C0>1<D2>1<C9><E8><CC>.
```

Comment: You added a cout... Does changing the string you emit to a [`u8` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444930/is-the-u8-string-literal-necessary-in-c11) make any difference?

Comment: An actual [mcve] with exact error messages would really help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing `#include "thread"`, you've said (by convention at least) to check the current directory for a `thread` file first. The problem is that you have a `thread` file in your current directory. Presumably, it's your executable from the first time you compiled. This is apparent by the errors, which explicitly say `./thread`.

You should include all standard headers via `#include <thread>` rather than `#include "thread"` - you never want to search elsewhere first for standard headers.

Comment: i used "thread" the first time too when it compiled fine, its only from second time that is fails compiling.

Comment: @Arup That's because the first time, you didn't have your `thread` executable, so searching the current directory produced nothing and the search continued on to include paths.