# c++11 how to convert a hex string into unicode string

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

Seems that even with C++11 this is not straightforward to do, e.g.,

```
string instring = "0x1234";  // hex string
string outstring = "ሴ"       // equivalent to "\u1234"
```

Assuming I only have this hexadecimal number as an input string passed down from some other place, which means I don't know the hex number beforehand.  What's the best way to achieve this?

Looks like this '\u' prefix only works when immediately followed by the hex number.

Ideas I tried and didn't work:

```
1. std::regex_replace(instring, "0x", "\\u");
2. sprintf();
```

Comment: Unicode defines code points. You need an encoding to somehow store the code point. What encoding do you want to use? The question seems slightly unclear to me. If you're defining literals, just define them with `'\u'`. If you're reading the desired characters from a file, just store them. If you're reading the sequence of hex values and you want to encode them to represent an actual code point, you need to parse them. What is your desire?

Comment: Yes, I should've clarified better. It's indeed the last case, where I only get the string from somewhere else. updated question too.

Comment: If nobody answers until tomorrow, I will provide an algorithm and some suggestions. Although, it'd be great if you showed us what you had tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::regex_replace` will not work, since it works withing the actual data stored. The `"\\u"` character alters how the text will be stored in data. Simply replacing it won't work - it's too late.

You *could* play a little bit with encoding. Pretty sure there must be a library for that (I wrote a [parser](https://github.com/Fureeish/EncodingParser/blob/master/main.cpp) which takes a raw UTF-8 file and outputs the code points of multibyte characters, but it's *really* limited as of right now, *plus it's not properly tested*), but we can try to implement our own, limited version, to understand what's going on inside.

First of all, why UTF-8? There is really no good reason not to. It depends on your [local encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739070/char-encoding), but you can adjust it to your needs.

Example of a code written in UTF-8 editor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    std::string str = "\u1234";
    for(char c : str) {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(static_cast<uint8_t>(c)) << ' ';
    }
}
```

will produce `11100001 10001000 10110100`.

You can read about `std::bitset` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). If you're surprised by the result (you're not familiar with how UTF-8 works), I encourage you to [watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4&t=0s) a great video on that.

---

Back to the topic. The goal is to compute the **hex** value, convert it to a sequence of UTF-8 bytes (*characters*) and store it into `std::string`.

Pseudocode:

```
string := input;
hex := convertToHex(string);
sequence := hexToUTF8(hex);
output := seqToString(sequence);
```

We assume that `input` will be provided as hex string. To convert a hex string to a decimal value, we can use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::string input = "0x1234";
std::stringstream stream{};
stream << std::hex << input;
int val;
stream >> val;
```

`val` will be equal to `4660`.

Now, we need to construct a sequence of UTF-8 bytes given this value. We can use an existing library, `std::wstring_convert`, but **beware**, it is considerd **deprecated** as of `C++17`. You are better of using a [different library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20419914/7151494), but we'll stick to this one just to demonstrate the example:

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    int val = 4660; // 0x1234
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> converter;
    std::string u8str = converter.to_bytes(val);
}
```

`u8str` is now equal to `"\u1234"`.

---

Full example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int hex_value(const std::string_view str) {
    std::stringstream stream{};
    stream << std::hex << str;
    int parsed;
    stream >> parsed;
    return parsed;
}

std::string map_to_utf8(const int val) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> converter;
    return converter.to_bytes(static_cast<char32_t>(val));
}

int main() {
    std::string input = "0x1234"; // read from file, let's assume...

    const auto value = hex_value(input);
    const auto str   = map_to_utf8(value);

    using namespace std::literals;
    assert(str == "\u1234"s && "\u1234"s == "ሴ"s); // passes
}
```

Comment: thanks for your elaborated examples and explanations! This really helps! What I missed is the unicode rendering piece, so the code snippet and external links are really helpful! One minor thing is that I needed to remove 's' from "u1234"s' to make it compile.

Comment: do you know if there would be better unicode string support in C++17 and onwards, especially when std::wstring_convert is going to be deprecated then? I meant native support in C++ standard and STL.

Comment: @galactica, glad my solution has helped you! If it solved your issue, consider accepting it by clicking the green tick below the score so the future visitors will know that this indeed solved the original problem. Regarding the `""s` - it's a *string literal operator*, available from `C++14`. You can read more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (recommended). As for the native support for various encodings, I think we're out of luck for some time. `C++20`'s feature list is completed and covers nothing related to our problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the further details! Too bad we're still not in the stage of having this fully solved in STL. As for that ""s format, it's probably worthy mentioning in the comments that that's available in C++14 and onwards.